# FlatPicker in Django Edit custom form showing time, only days

Tags: django, flatpickr

I have a Django app, with `new` template where datetimepicker works well. I created an `edit` template but the widget do not load automatically, so I added them. But for some reason, i do not know how to bring the `datetimepicker`, I can only get the `datepicker`.
Does anybody knows please ?

The precise line in the `edit` template looks like:

```
<div>
<input id="Restriction_Start_Date_id" type="text" name="Restriction_Start_Date" value="{{ restricted_name_obj.Restriction_Start_Date|date:'n/j/Y G:i'  }}" class="form form-control datepicker" >
</div>
```

[image]

While on the new template I have :

```
<div>{{ form.Restriction_Start_Date.label_tag }}</div>
<div>
{{ form.Restriction_Start_Date.errors }}
 {{ form.Restriction_Start_Date }}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, I used the CDN and the following :

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr@4.5.2/dist/flatpickr.min.css"type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="Restriction_Start_Date" required="" id="Restriction_Start_Date" fp_config="{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;fp_14&quot;, &quot;picker_type&quot;: &quot;DATETIME&quot;, &quot;linked_to&quot;: &quot;fp_13&quot;, &quot;options&quot;: {&quot;mode&quot;: &quot;single&quot;, &quot;dateFormat&quot;: &quot;Y-m-d H:i:S&quot;, &quot;altInput&quot;: true, &quot;enableTime&quot;: true}}"class="flatpickr-input" value="{{ restricted_name_obj.Restriction_Start_Date|date:'n/j/Y G:i' }}">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr@4.5.2/dist/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/monim67/django-flatpickr@1.0.0/static/js/django-flatpickr.js"></script>
```

(Not beautiful but it will do the job for now.